# PHP / Symfony3 Memory Leak downloading images

Tags: php, parsing, memory-leaks, symfony

I am developing a product parser and I need to download the associated image for each product. I have a service (I am using Symfony 3) to achieve this task. The main methods are these:

```
public function getMediaFromUrl($img) {
    $info = getimagesize($img);
    $size = $this->_remoteImageSize($img);
    $size = $size / 1000;
    $image = false;
    if ($size < 500) {
        $extension = image_type_to_extension($info[2]);
        //$binaryImageContent = file_get_contents($img);
        $imageFilename = $this->generateImageFilename($extension);
        $imagePath = $this->webFolder."/" . $imageFilename;
        //file_put_contents($imagePath, $binaryImageContent);
        copy($img,$imagePath);
        $image = $this->mediaManager->create();
        $image->setBinaryContent($imagePath);
        $image->setContext('product');
        $image->setProviderName('sonata.media.provider.image');
        $this->mediaManager->save($image);
        //unset($binaryImageContent);
    }
    return $image;
}

private function _remoteImageSize($url) {
    $filesize = false;
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $filesize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $filesize;
}
```

The XML that I have to parse has near 10.000 products. In each iteration, I print `memory_get_usage()` because every time I try to run the parse I get and *out of memory error*.

```
69694232
69755032
69961544
70171160
70380840
70525528
```

As you can see, it raises until waste 128Mb and throw out of memory exception. The other parts of the parser works fine because if I comment this part it ends without any exception (and the memory remains near 32029328). I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

I get the image with php `copy()` function and then generate the associated entity ( SonataMedia ) in order to persist it to database. Every 20 iterations I do the following:

```
 if ($count % $this->batchSize == 0) {
     $this->em->flush();
     $this->em->clear();
     gc_collect_cycles();
 }
```

So I don't thing doctrine is causing the leak (and as I said before, if I comment the functions to get the image it works well).

Any idea about this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you create an image but I don't see you [destroying](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagedestroy.php) it.

Comment: And how do yo destroy it? With unset?